# How to change customise a slider in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, slider

How do i change the default thickness of a slider bar(of 'react-native' library) ?
I couldn't find relevant props in the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting answer here
[How to style a Slider on Android with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665617/how-to-style-a-slider-on-android-with-react-native)

Here is what you could do with the props (I will let you pick the styles from the link above):

```
<Slider 
  thumbTintColor={'#0072C6'}
  minimumTrackTintColor={'#0072C6'}
  maximumTrackTintColor={'#000'}></Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in `style` props. As it says in the documentation check `StyleSheet.js` and `ViewStylePropTypes.js`

Comment: I have checked the documentation and the source code but I cannot find `StyleSheet.js` or `ViewStylePropTypes.js`