# React native, slide bar to render image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an app and I want to create slider like that to change emoji. I searched for packages but I unable to find package like that, so I used react native slider but facing problem with it, like unable to change height of slider and how to render image? So anyone can tell me how can I make slider like that?

[image]

Comment: potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665617/how-to-style-a-slider-on-android-with-react-native

Comment: I already tried that didn't worked and in that there is nothing for rendering image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to achieve, you would like the slider to change the image as the user slides?

So the slider only operates in integers and if you set the step to 1 then it will only operate in whole integers.

```
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
const [currentSelection, setCurrentSelection] = useState(selections[0]);

 <Slider
   style={{width: 200, height: 80}}
   minimumValue={0}
   maximumValue={3}
   step={1}
   minimumTrackTintColor="#0000ff"
   maximumTrackTintColor="#0000ff"
   onValueChange={(val) => setSelection(selections[val])}
/>
```

You would then have an object of your images and information

```
const selections = [
  {id: 0, title: 'poor', image: '/* Your Image */'}
  {id: 1, title: 'ok', image: '/* Your Image */'}
  {id: 2, title: 'good', image: '/* Your Image */'}
  {id: 3, title: 'excellent', image: '/* Your Image */'}
]
```

Then in your image component you would just change the image based on the state

```
<Image source={currentSelection.image} height={....} width={...} />
```

Obviously your need to style your components to match and achieving the dots under each step might be difficult as I cannot see a prop in the library that provides this functionality.

Tested and works.