# React Native, change the height of react-native-community/slider and thumb icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I used `@react-native-community/slider` for my app, but I'm facing a problem that it's height is not changing, it's width is changing but not height, anyone know why? and also I want to render value of slider like in the blue container inside the slider thumb, is there a way to do that? Please Help

That's my code of slider

```
<View>
          <Text style={[style.fontSize15Med, styles.font15]}>
            Number of surveys
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.daysCont}>
            <Text style={[style.fontSize12Med, styles.surveys]}>
              {this.state.surveys}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Slider
            style={{width: 320, height: 30, marginLeft: 40}}
            minimumValue={0}
            maximumValue={10}
            step={1}
            maximumTrackTintColor={colors.DarkBlue}
            minimumTrackTintColor={colors.primary}
            thumbTintColor={colors.skyBlue}
            value={this.state.surveys}
            onValueChange={(val) => this.setState({surveys: val})}
          />
        </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As for Mar 2022, there's no property to change the slider thickness, but there are a few workaround options.

1. Use scaleY CSS styling: `transform: [{ scaleY: 2 }]`

```html
<Slider
  style={{ width: 320, transform: [{ scaleY: 2 }] }}
  ...
/>
```

This example will double the slider bar thickness. The downside is that it increases the knob button.

2. Use an alternative Slider:

   https://github.com/miblanchard/react-native-slider
3. Create a fake slider using View components, and place it over the actual Slider:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/47246453/1772990

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom thumb image like

```
const thumbImage = require('shared/img/slider-thumb.png');

<Slider
   .......
   thumbImage={thumbImage}
   style={{width: 200, height: 40}} // height, width
/>
```

More info found here [thumbimage](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider#thumbimage)

Comment: can I render text instead on image?

Comment: No, just icon you can place it

Comment: ok, so there is no way I can render text, what about height of slider?

Comment: You can't render text inside slider view. I have updated my answer for height, please check.